# Safari viewport-fit cover not taking entire screen height

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm having trouble using the entire height of the screen on a home screen web app on iOS. If I use viewport-fit:contain it leaves the space for the status bar blank on top and everything else works great. But I want to use the entire space and when I set it to cover it moves the viewport up and leaves the space on the bottom and crops the view as you can see from the screenshot.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
<body style="height: 100vh;">
  <div style="background-color: chocolate; font-size: 44pt; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;">TESTING</div>
</body>
```

[image: screenshot]